# I am confused what form_valid() or form_invalid() accomplished

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I just started to use class based views instead of functions so sorry if this is an obvious question but what does `form_valid()` and `form_invalid()` do in a class that inherits from `FormView`? Django says that:

> "This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed. It should
>   return an `HttpResponse`"

But what I don't get is how is it validated? I have additional checks I need to perform on the form before I can save the data (such as when signing up, making sure the two passwords entered are the same). How would I be able to add more checks if I want to?

Here's the code I've been working with

forms.py

```py
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    alias = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_pass = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    # used to verify if the passwords match
    def pwd_match(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            cd = self.cleaned_data
            if cd.get('password') == cd.get('confirm_pass'):
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def fields_correct(self):
        if self.pwd_match() and self.is_valid():
            return True
        return False
```

views.py

```py
class SignupFormView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    form_class = SignupForm
    template_name = 'forum/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # here I want to make sure that the passwords match and then save the user
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here,

1- you can add a [clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method to your form for the extra validation you need to do. So in your forms, you will have something like,

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    # do some validation on your fields
    ...
```

2- you can add the extra logic in your `is_valid` function in the view and return the user to the same page with an error message. A little messy but in some cases, you need to hack around.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is not what form_valid does. That method is called once the form has been successfully validated.

Whether you use a function-based or a class-based view, this kind of thing belongs in the form. You should remove your `pwd_match` and `fields_correct` method, and instead define a single `clean` method:

```
def pwd_match(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd.get('password') != cd.get('confirm_pass'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('passwords do not match')
        return cd
```